# Загрузка файлов на сервер Node без использования Express и др. модулей

Tags: node.js

Изучаю Node. Хочу разобраться как происходит загрузка файлов на сервер и что для этого надо. Гуглил, но везде используются Express и другие модули. 
У меня получается загрузить данные, но они записываются в формате "base64" и файл становится не читабельным. Использую вот такую конструкцию:

```
var data ="";
            req.on('data', function(chunk){
                data += chunk;
            })
            req.on("end", function(){
                fs.writeFile("000.txt", data, function(err){
                    if (err) console.log("Ошибка записи");
                })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для записи раскодированных данных в файл есть несколько вариантов. Самый простой для вашего примера - это добавить дополнительный параметр функции writeFile, который указывает кодировку данных:

```
fs.writeFile("000.txt", data, 'base64', function(err){
```

при этом данные будут записаны в файл в раскодированном виде.

Comment: П.С.: Правда возникла необходимость еще немного дополнить код. Пришлось разбить "data" на части, т.к в "data" хранилось полностью тело запроса: с MIME типом файла и кодировкой.  Вставка выглядит так: var finish = data.split(","). Ну и в запись передается не "data", a "finish[1]".